Is there a metric, a solution to Einstein's field equations, for a single body in a space of uniform non-zero density?
The Swarzschild metric describes a single body in an empty space with zero density, while the FLRW metric is presumably for a space with uniform  non-zero density but no single body. But is there a metric as described in the question?
The single body could be an inert mass or perhaps a black hole. The latter might be simplest. The uniform density could be due to matter in the form of dust or perhaps radiation.
If such a metric exists, could it be described in layman's terms? Eg would the single body grow or expand and at what rate? It would presumably be a function of the density. Would the space have curvature?
The reason behind the question is this. I have made a conjecture; if the density of material outside the black hole is the same as the density of the black hole, the black hole will expand at the speed of light. For the purpose of this conjecture, the volume of a black hole, used to calculate the density, is the volume of external space that the black hole occupies.

de Sitter-Schwarzschild metric describes a spherical mass in an expanding universe. The Vaidya metric describes a spherical mass that is emitting (or absorbing) null dust,

I guess the Oppenheimer-Snyder metric also counts but that's just a Schwarzschild and FLRW metric stitched together.

Have a look at this answer of mine.
